# How to Find Top N selling items at a given date using SQL/T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The user provides a date and a number N. The N best selling items on that day are produced. The title, the company, the current stock and the number of copies sold for that best seller is shown for that date. The output should be ordered according to sales: the best selling item should be first, the second best will follow, etc.

DBMS: SQL Server

The tables:

- `Item` (upc (pk), title, type, category, company, year, price, stock)
- `PurchaseItem` (receiptId (pk), upc (pk), quantity)

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT TOP(N) 
    DATE(year) as date, I.title, I.company, I.stock, P.quantity, I.upc
FROM 
    Item I, Purchase P
WHERE 
    I.upc = P.upc
GROUP BY 
    I.upc
ORDER BY 
    SUM(P.quantity) DESC
```

Just need some help correcting this and checking it.

Thanks!

Comment: You have tagged the question MySQL, but you are using SQL Server syntax.  And, you are using implicit joins (yuck!) instead of `join`.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Where is the Date field coming from ? I don;t see it either Item or Purchase as you defined it in the question.

Comment: Whoops, meant to say year.

Comment: Now I am more confused. Is the Year INT or DATETIME or DATE ?

Comment: Another Quesiton: Is this MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: I believe it would be a DATE, so I guess I wouldn't need DATE() in the SELECT? and SQL server

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Based on the accepted answer you are using **MySQL**, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you can get total sold quantity for each item on a given date in cte

You can then apply top logic to filter them with order by on total quantity sold.

```
declare @inputDate datetime

;with cte 
as
( select I.upc, SUM(quantity) as TotalSold
  from Item I
  join Purchase P
  on I.upc = P.upc
  and I.date = @inputDate
  group by I.upc
)
SELECT TOP 10 I.date, I.upc, I.title, I.company, I.stock, cte.TotalSold
FROM Item I
join cte
on I.upc = cte.upc
order by cte.TotalSold desc
```